# How to tell what method is being used by a function call when `methods` fails?

Tags: r, oop, methods, r-maptools

Might as well let the cat out of the bag and say that I have been trying for about a day to figure out what is happening when I call `plot` for an object of class `SpatialPolygons*`. My instinct is to look for `plot.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, the approach which works for any number of other examples I've seen & encountered, but this failed.

Quick example:

[US States .shp file](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_state_500k.zip) here.

```
library(maptools)
us.states<-readShapePoly("cb_2014_us_state_5m.shp")
plot(us.states)
```

[image: A sample plot. It shows the polygons of all the US states and territories placed on an invisible globe. It's hard to read, but the plot is not the main thing for this question.]

A bit dumpy but whatever--the point is that a simple call to `plot` and somewhere deep down `R` knew which method to call in order to give us a representation of all the shapes.

After searching around a bit, I tried two of the other approaches suggested by various SO Q&As, first and foremost:

```
> methods(plot)
 [1] plot.aareg*                         plot.acf*                          
 [3] plot,ANY,ANY-method                 plot.cox.zph*                      
 [5] plot.data.frame*                    plot.decomposed.ts*                
 [7] plot.default                        plot.dendrogram*                   
 [9] plot.density*                       plot.ecdf                          
[11] plot.factor*                        plot.formula*                      
[13] plot.function                       plot.hclust*                       
[15] plot.histogram*                     plot.HoltWinters*                  
[17] plot.isoreg*                        plot.lm*                           
[19] plot.medpolish*                     plot.mlm*                          
[21] plot.ppr*                           plot.prcomp*                       
[23] plot.princomp*                      plot.profile.nls*                  
[25] plot.raster*                        plot.shingle*                      
[27] plot,SpatialGrid,missing-method     plot,SpatialLines,missing-method   
[29] plot,Spatial,missing-method         plot,SpatialPixels,missing-method  
[31] plot,SpatialPoints,missing-method   plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method
[33] plot.spec*                          plot.spline*                       
[35] plot.stepfun                        plot.stl*                          
[37] plot.survfit*                       plot.table*                        
[39] plot.times*                         plot.trellis*                      
[41] plot.ts                             plot.tskernel*                     
[43] plot.TukeyHSD*                      plot.xyVector*                     
[45] plot.zoo*
```

The answer would appear to be in slots 27-32; however, each is followed by a vexing comma! No mention that this is possible in `?methods` and `?plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method` is an error. A quick search for `missing-method` turns up nothing of use and there's again no mention in `?methods`.

OK; moving on. What about `getS3method`? `getMethod`? `getMethods`? `getAllMethods`??

```
> getS3method("plot","SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
Error in getS3method("plot", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") : 
  S3 method 'plot.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' not found

> getMethod("plot","SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
Error in getMethod("plot", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") : 
  no method found for function 'plot' and signature SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
```

The latter two are deprecated & also return nothing.

So apparently these functions are just a stand-in for my first instincts.

So now what? How can I tell which method is being called by `plot` when it is passed a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`? Is there any general approach to this problem that supersedes the approach I used above?

## Edit:

Sort of by accident I stumbled upon [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/as.data.frame.SpatialPolygons) (=`` ?`Spatial-Polygons-class` `` ) which says:

> The `plot` method for spatial polygons takes the following arguments:

but it still doesn't say what that method is, exactly.

Comment: The "vexing comma" **is** mentioned in `?methods`. The second paragraph in the *Details* sections says, "S4 method signatures are printed as 'generic,class-method'; S4 allows for multiple dispatch, so there may be several classes in the signature 'generic,A,B-method'.". And how to view the source for S4 methods is described in the answer to [How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/271616).

Comment: Just to clarify, the `methods` function never "told you which method was use". It only ever told you which methods were available from the loaded packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer a couple of questions raised by Gregor. The `methods` function did not formerly display results for S4-methods, but now it does. Doing a search in the NEWS document I see this was added with version 3.2.0:

```
methods() reports S4 in addition to S3 methods; output is simplified when the class 
argument is used. .S3methods() and methods::.S4methods() report S3 and S4 methods separately.
```

SpatialPolygons are S4 objects, and so have slots and S4-methods that are dispatched. You can display an S4 method with:

```
showMethods(f='plot', classes='SpatialPolygons', includeDefs=TRUE)
#    ---- result ---
Function: plot (package graphics)
x="SpatialPolygons", y="missing"
function (x, y, ...) 
plot.SpatialPolygons(x, ...)
```

That tells you that there is an S4 function for that class. You can execute either `sp:::SpatialPolygons` or `getAnywhere(plot.SpatialPolygons)` to see the function code. (Often that call using `includeDefs=TRUE` would display the R-code, but not here.) The result for `methods(plot)` when package 'sp' is loaded tell you that there are 8 different plot S4 methods registered in the workspace. The items following the commas are the "signatures" that are used for function dispatch. "missing-method" refers to situations where the second argument is not specified, wherein the `missing` function executed inside a function body would return `TRUE`:

```
  [1] plot,ANY,ANY-method                 plot,color,ANY-method              
  [3] plot,Spatial,missing-method         plot,SpatialGrid,missing-method    
  [5] plot,SpatialLines,missing-method    plot,SpatialPixels,missing-method  
  [7] plot,SpatialPoints,missing-method   plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method
```

This will show you what then gets used to dispatch a `plot`-call when the the object passed to it does not match any of the S4 methods:

```
showMethods(f='plot', classes='ANY', includeDefs=TRUE)
Function: plot (package graphics)
x="ANY", y="ANY"
function (x, y, ...) 
UseMethod("plot")


x="color", y="ANY"
function (x, y, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (x, y, pch = 20, cex = 3) 
    pairs(coords(x), col = hex(x, fix = TRUE), pch = pch, cex = cex)
    .local(x, y, ...)
}
```

Basically the R interpreter first checks to see if any S4 methods are appropriate, and failing that, will start going through the S3 methods until it gets to `plot.default`.

```
> getMethod(f='plot', signature=c(x='SpatialPolygons', y='missing'))
Method Definition:

function (x, y, ...) 
plot.SpatialPolygons(x, ...)
<environment: namespace:sp>

Signatures:
        x                 y        
target  "SpatialPolygons" "missing"
defined "SpatialPolygons" "missing"
```

And BTW I see this in the response from `?getMethods`:

```
## Deprecated in 2010 and defunct in 2015 for \code{table = FALSE}:
getMethods(f, where, table = FALSE)
```

Comment: any idea why it says missing method even when sp is specifically loaded? my initial reaction to the answers was that this was maptools calling sp functions even though I didn't load sp directly...

Comment: @MichaelChirico: "missing" doesn't mean the method is missing. It's a special type of class in the signature (the other is "ANY").

Comment: @joshuaulrich is that intentionally confusing or is it just me?

Comment: ?methods documents the comma: "S4 method signatures are printed as  'generic,class-method'; S4 allows for multiple dispatch, so there may be several classes in the signature 'generic,A,B-method'". `includeDefs=TRUE` _does_ display the R code -- sp:::plot.SpatialPolygons. `selectMethod(plot, c("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "missing"))` is like getMethod(), but takes inheritance into account. It indicates 'target' and 'defined' method; with the defined method in hand, the help page is the name of the method returned by methods(plot), ?"plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method"

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer: the method is `sp:::plot.SpatialPolygons`. I have no idea why those commas are showing up in the results of `methods(plot)`; `plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method` makes no sense to me (and I see it too).

I found the answer by causing an error. I don't have your shape file, so I took the example from `help("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class")`, which I got to from `?SpatialPolygons"`. The example is below:

```
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
plot(SpP, col = 1:3, pbg="white")
```

I then changed the plot call to give an error:

```
plot(SpP, col = kasjdhfkjasdfhkas, pbg = "white")
# Error in plot.SpatialPolygons(x, ...) : object 'kasjdhfkjasdfhkas' not found
```

(should work unless you have `kasjdhfkjasdfhkas` defined in your workspace as a vector). Sure enough,

```
sp:::plot.SpatialPolygons
```

showed the code for the method.

Comment: these are both great answers--yours definitely provides some great tools for investigation if met with similar problems in the future. thank you.